# Android - Header content-length equal -1

Tags: android, file, download, size, content-length

I'm downloading a file in my android app and I want to display a progressbar. I need to know the total file size by using this method : [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29). 
The problem is that I always get -1 despite the fact that it's set on the server and I can see it from my computer.

This is the code :

```
URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
ucon.connect();
int length = ucon.getContentLength();
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not related to Android, most probably it was not sent from the server..please use any sniffing tool to make sure the content length header is there.

Comment: I did, I used curl and this site : http://web-sniffer.net/.
Here is the result :
curl -I http://rock1.ceypasbien.fr/classification/export
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 22 Apr 2012 16:20:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AF002E1DED4D6A167CAC0DB1F4762081; Path=/

**Content-Length: 516941**

Comment: okay..please try to get the length after getting the input stream ucon.getInputStream()

Comment: It seems to work on the simulator but not on a real device (galaxy tab 8.9 / android 3.2 or galaxy ace / 2.3.3).

Comment: are you downloading some large content, some operators could decide to  omit this header and send the data in chunks through their servers. are you using wifi or 2g/3g networks?

Comment: I use both 3G and wifi and I only download this file, so only 500Ko.